# How to get facebook notification in iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, facebook, notifications, fbconnect

I am developing a iPhone application in which i want to get notification in my application when ever my friends write or post on my wall.

On Facebook web site they saw notification, now i want to get notification in my iPhone application.

Can anybody know how to get those notification through iPhone SDK ?

Any example or idea is very thankful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't have an iOS app that continuously checks Facebook in the background and since you can't bring Facebook to send a push notification to your app, you would have to set up a web server that continuously polls Facebook for changes and then sends a push notification to the iOS device when it detects a change.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but if you want to push changes in facebook to somewhere it might be a good idea to look into the [Facebook Realtime Updates API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/). As it notifies directly of any changes in facebook you've subscribed to.